# Getting error while using command add-migration in Visual studio 2017 Core 1.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

i am getting error in VS 2017 Core 1.0 project, Please find below error.

add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
2. Close Package Manager Console
3. Restart Visual Studio